# Integrating a function and then plotting it's graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've been working on this code for some hours and it seems I'm doing something wrong which I just can't figure out. I have a function which I integrate and then plot it's values. But the graph I get looks strange. I expected some form of an exponential function but the one I get is far away from my anticipations, and when I try changing some of my constants, it does still behave in a strange manner. This is how the code looks like:

```
y = 0:0.5:D;
p = 65.5;
k = 1;
D =10:0.5:100; %Create a vector for D

M =zeros(1,181); %an array
for j = k:181 %For loop for all water values

  M(k) = integral(@(y) Func5(p,D,k,y),0,D(k));
  k+1;  
end

plot(D,M)
title('Hydrostatic pressure in bars');
xlabel('water level in fot');
ylabel('pressure i bars');
```

And this is the code for my function:

```
function FD = Func5(p,D,k,y)
 w = 40-20*exp(-(0.01*y))*2; %Width of the dam
 FD = p.*(D(k)-y).*w; %Claculate the pressure
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: it's graph/it's value  -->  its graph, its value

Comment: Hey Wolfgang! Thanks for your help but I don't think I'm getting what you are conveying to me. Could you help explaining a little more?

Comment: Can you indicate which ODE you are solving? There are some issues with your code: 1. you need `D` for vector `y` but don't specify it, later you then redefine `D` which may introduce bugs if you are not careful. 2. Why do you manually increase `j` using `k+1` in the loop? it seems to me simply using `j=1:181` and `M(j)` works just fine. 3. It would be best not to use a for-loop and vectorize the call to `integral` but since i am not sure what you are solving, it is difficult to say if that is possible. 4. It is unclear what the different variables (D, k, etc) are...

Comment: @LloydKizito -- I'm simply pointing out a persistent grammar error in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem you encounter is that your for-loop probably doesn't do what you expect.

```
k = 1;
M =zeros(1,181);
for j = k:181 
  M(k) = integral(@(y) Func5(p,D,k,y),0,D(k));
  k+1;  # does not increase k
end
```

The problem here is that the statement `k+1` is useless and does not increase `k` which i think is what you are after. The problem with this is that `j` is still increased each iteration but the values of the integral are assigned to `M(k)` which remain `M(1)` rather than increase with the loop. Also the argument `D(k)` remains unchanged which i guess should instead change with the iteration aswell.

try this instead:

```
M =zeros(1,181);
for j = 1:181
  M(j) = integral(@(y) Func5(p,D,j,y),0,D(j));
end
```

this give me atleast a graph which resembles some sort of exponential function.

Some general advice about your code: try using comments which add useful information to improve readability. `M =zeros(1,181); %an array` is not a useful comment because i can already see this is 'an array', what i cant see is what `M` means; a better comment would be `% preallocate the results vector` , the same applies for `D =10:0.5:100; %Create a vector for D`; what is `D`? and for that matter all other variables? Often it is also better to use meaningful variable names like `results` or `pressure` rather than `D` and `M`. Furthermore, in a function like `Func5` it is useful to include a larger comment block at the top to say what the function calculates (which equation) and what its in/outputs are.

Comment: You are awesome nluigi! I worked just great!!